# Order results by number of votes

Tags: 8, polls

I want to display the pool result output by the [Poll](https://drupal.org/project/poll) module by the number of votes, instead of the default order which is the same for all the polls.

I made two attempts:

1. Creating a poll view displaying the choice field, with the choice target sort criteria
   Unfortunately, it doesn't sort them accordingly.
2. Altering the template file used by the Poll module (poll-results.html.twig) where `<dl> {{ results }} </dl>` is used to show the poll result
   I'm not sure where the variable is created and how I can change its value.

How can I alter the order used to show the pool result?

Comment: Hi. There's already a feature request for this functionality on the modules issue queue and a first patch. You may try this and provide feedback to the module maintainers.

https://www.drupal.org/project/poll/issues/3180178

Comment: Yes I've tried the patch, it doesn't work as expected, actually it doesn't add the field it says.